# Prepopulate Values in token input textbox from database using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, token

Below is my code For adding number of choices in text as tag using tokeninput.After Selecting tags while save button i will make selection as array and save it in database as US,Ireland in country column.After saving want to prepopulate save data as tag using jquery method.Below is a reference code for this process.

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/token-input.css" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<script>
      var country_list=[ 
{id: 1, name: "UK"}, 
{id: 2, name: "CANADA"}, 
{id: 3, name: "IRELAND"}, 
{id: 4, name: "SINGAPORE"}, 
{id: 5, name: "AUSTRALIA"}, 
{id: 6, name: "NEWZEALAND"}, 
{id: 7, name: "SWITZERLAND"}, 
{id: 8, name: "CYPRUS"}, 
{id: 9, name: "FRANCE"}, 
{id: 10, name: "MALAYSIA"}, 
{id: 11, name: "ITALY"}, 
{id: 12, name: "SWEDEN"}, 
{id: 13, name: "GERMANY"}, 
{id: 14, name: "USA"}, 
{id: 15, name: "DUBAI"}, 
{id: 16, name: "SPAIN"}, 
{id: 17, name: "LITHUANIA"}, 
{id: 18, name: "NETHERLANDS"}, 
{id: 19, name: "LATVIA"}, 
{id: 20, name: "SOUTH AFRICA"}, 
{id: 21, name: "OTHERS"} 
]; 
var selected_countries=<?php echo json_encode(explode(",",$country));?>; 
//alert(selected_countries);
var populate_list=[]; 
var index; 
for (index = 0; index < country_list.length; ++index) { 
console.log(country_list[index]); 
if(selected_countries.indexOf(country_list[index].name)>-1){ 

populate_list.push(country_list[index]); 
} 
} 
var prepopulate = { 
prePopulate : populate_list 
}; 

$("#country").tokenInput(country_list,prepopulate);
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
 <input type="text" name="country"  id="country">
```

And For saving result all selected text in database i used

AJAX code

```
var arr1 = $('#country').tokenInput("get");
            var names1 = [];
            $.each(arr1, function(i, obj)
            {
             names1.push(obj.name);
            });
            var country=names1.join();
```

And result Database Side AND UI Side

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

> prePopulate 
>     Prepopulate the tokeninput with existing data. Set to an
>   array of JSON objects, eg: [{id: 3, name: "test"}, {id: 5, name:
>   "awesome"}] to pre-fill the input.

```
var country_list=[ 
{id: 1, name: "UK"}, 
{id: 2, name: "CANADA"}, 
{id: 3, name: "IRELAND"}, 
{id: 4, name: "SINGAPORE"}, 
{id: 5, name: "AUSTRALIA"}, 
{id: 6, name: "NEWZEALAND"}, 
{id: 7, name: "SWITZERLAND"}, 
{id: 8, name: "CYPRUS"}, 
{id: 9, name: "FRANCE"}, 
{id: 10, name: "MALAYSIA"}, 
{id: 11, name: "ITALY"}, 
{id: 12, name: "SWEDEN"}, 
{id: 13, name: "GERMANY"}, 
{id: 14, name: "USA"}, 
{id: 15, name: "DUBAI"}, 
{id: 16, name: "SPAIN"}, 
{id: 17, name: "LITHUANIA"}, 
{id: 18, name: "NETHERLANDS"}, 
{id: 19, name: "LATVIA"}, 
{id: 20, name: "SOUTH AFRICA"}, 
{id: 21, name: "OTHERS"} 
]; 

var selected_countries=<?php echo json_encode(explode($country));?>; 
var populate_list=[]; 
var index; 
for (index = 0; index < country_list.length; ++index) { 

if(selected_countries.indexOf(country_list[index].name)>-1){ 
populate_list.push(country_list[index]); 
} 
} 
var prepopulate = { 
prepopulate : populate_list 
}; 

 $("#country").tokenInput(country_list,prepopulate);
```

Comment: Ya thts correct but i want to prepopulate from database value how can i do this.

Comment: You should just use json_encode() to encode your data from php.If you want details on that just give me your php code

Comment: Nothing special with php code. i just got value from ajax as UK,Ireland and i insert that value in country field

Comment: if(isset($_POST['country']))
    { 
        $country = $_POST['country'];
     }
     else
     {
        $country="";
     } $l2 = "UPDATE details
SET career_aspiring = '$career_aspiring' ,
    subject_want_study='$subject_want_study',
    level = '$level',
    country = '$country',
    specific_location ='$specific_location',
    specific_institution = '$specific_institution' ,
    comments ='$comments'
   WHERE per_email='$per_email'";

Comment: First of all is a bad idea to save all countries in the same column because then you cannot use this field in `JOINS`.But if you eventually decide to leave database structure as it is at least you should save id not name so you can use it later to prepopulate the input field

Comment: Then its okay if i save id in database and then how can i prepopulate it

Comment: do you have the country list saved in your database too so they are available in php? or only client side?Ideally you should have them stored in database too because if you later  change an id of a country the changes should be reflected to database too....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111218/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-george-pant).

Answer (score 1):

Change your input text box to following:

```
<input type="text" name="country"  id="country" value='<?php echo  $country; ?>' data-country='<?php echo  $country; ?>'>
```

Then add prePopulate parameter like following:

```
prePopulate: $('#country').data('country')
```

Comment: I want to take that value from database.As i shown in picture. I want to retrieve UK and Ireland from database and prepopulate it dynamically

Comment: It can be done in jquery itself but you are saving country name instead of id's in database. this will not match at frontend. Token matches id's

Comment: Then how can i do this. Give me some suggestion

Comment: Now i change it.i jsut saving id of corresponding data.and i tried with above code but its not prepopulated

Comment: did you checked your browser console if there is any error

Comment: It is showing value as undefined inside tag.And no error i found in console